# How to use $http.get function if we have set of url

Tags: javascript, http, youtube

In my situation I have 14 YouTube data url, and I need to pass using $http.get function to get the response...
But what is happening is it takes 1st url, but before getting response it is looping again and taking another url. After the last url it's start executing url and getting responses.

Code is:

```
var _getCategoriesCat=function(){ 

   for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){

       var catId = parseInt(items[i].id);
       var title = items[i].snippet.title;

       if(showMore.showMoreValue) {
          var url ="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&pageToken=10&regionCode=IN&type=video&videoCategoryId="+ catId +"&fields=items%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CregionCode&key=";
       } else {
          var url ="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=6&pageToken=10&regionCode=IN&type=video&videoCategoryId="+ catId +"&fields=items%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CregionCode&key=";
       }
       xhr.get(url, function(response){
            response.name = title;
            response = [response];
            _mContents.push(PV.yoohu.model.arrayList(PV.yoohu.model.youtubeCategoryModel, response));
     })
  }
       _getLatest();
}
```

I have 14 items, if I use this code 4th url response comes 1st and 1st url response comes later. I want  responses one by one.
If anyone knows please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Move fetching of a single URL into a separate function and in should take inde position on the URL in the array. And on completion of a url, call the same with the index incremented. You can try this (code not tested)

```
 function fetchInfo(i) {
   i = i || 0;
   var catId = parseInt(items[i].id);
   var title = items[i].snippet.title;

   if (showMore.showMoreValue) {
     var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&pageToken=10&regionCode=IN&type=video&videoCategoryId=" + catId + "&fields=items%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CregionCode&key=";
   } else {
     var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=6&pageToken=10&regionCode=IN&type=video&videoCategoryId=" + catId + "&fields=items%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CregionCode&key=";
   }

   xhr.get(url, function(response) {
     response.name = title;
     response = [response];
     _mContents.push(PV.yoohu.model.arrayList(PV.yoohu.model.youtubeCategoryModel, response));
     if (i < items.length) fetchInfo(i + 1);
   })
 }

 fetchInfo()
```